# Use the same value for the next 10 occurrences in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have a column with values  and I need to create a new column where the first instance of 1 is repeated for the next 5 occurrences.

Comment: Current: [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; Expected: [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]

Comment: are you looking for something like this ?https://stackoverflow.com/a/40318545/6561141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
 x =  [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
 a = x[:]

 for i,j in enumerate(a):
   if j!=0:   x[i:i+6] = [j]*6
 x
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

You will have to create a copy ie `a` to be used in the enumeration since `x` will be changing